# InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Jr1szu/Django/

Tags: python, django, package, virtualenv, pinax

I'm trying to start a Pinax Project for Django.
I setup my Python Virtual Environment.
Upgraded setup tools.
Upgraded pip.
Installed Pinax.
Then when I tried 'pinax start blog my_site', it gave the following error:

```
Installing Django...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pinax", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 700, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 680, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1027, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 873, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 508, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 63, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 508, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pcli.py", line 97, in start
    pip_install("Django")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pcli.py", line 23, in pip_install
    command.run(opts, [package])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 707, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Jr1szu/Django/
```

I've tried making a python virtual environment inside my conda environment. Also tried making a standalone python environment. Neither solved it. Also tried installing django using pip.

Gave the following error:

```
sudo pip install django
The directory '/home/scarlet/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/scarlet/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting django
  Downloading Django-2.0.tar.gz (8.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.0MB 62kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-SNP9W5/django/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SNP9W5/django/
```

What would you suggest?
Thank you for the read!

Answer (score 2):

It appears like you are using python 2; if that is correct `Django` version 2 only supports python 3. Please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#python-compatibility

You could try installing a lower version of `Django`:

```
pip install "Django<2"
```

Comment: I tried that. Now I'm using Python 2.7.12 and Django (1, 11, 8, u'final', 0). Yet no change.

Comment: Can you please post the traceback?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sAwbhLvz Of course. There you go. Please do give suggestions.

Comment: Have you got `python-dev` installed? e.g. `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: Can you please also check that `setuptools` is available? With pip you can do `pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Comment: it is installed. but still no change

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
pip3 install django
```